# Create a grid of pie charts with Pandas or Seaborn

Tags: pandas, seaborn

Given this DataFrame:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({"A": [11, 3, 7], "B": [4, 12, 8], "C": [5, 5, 5]}, index=["s1", "s2", "s3"] )
```

Corresponding to the grades of students s1, s2, and s3 over a semester. Student s1, for example, got 11 A's, 4 B's and 5 C's. There were 20 assignments total.

I would like to create a collection of small pie charts showing the proportions of A,B and C grades, for each students.

In my real data set I might have 80 students so I would like a grid of say 8 by 10 little tiny pie charts, labeled with the students Id.

I've pored over the docs, but I can't find a good elegant solution other than literally iterating with Python. But I feel there ought to be a nicer way.

### The real test dataset

When I used the dataset below (basically the same as above) and then try variations of this to create my grid of pies, the pies are always squashed in different directions.

```
df.T.plot.pie(subplots=True, figsize=[6,50], layout=[10,4], legend=False)
```

I can't make sense out of what fig size is doing. I've looked through the docs and plenty of Stack Overflow to help me understand the unites. Basically, the parameter seems to be ignored. Here's the data:

```
$ cat data.csv
,A,B,C,D
as9.2,31,0,0,0
as22.2,17,9,1,4
as21.1,16,15,0,0
as16.2,15,12,4,0
as17.1,12,15,4,0
as7.1,12,8,11,0
coursetotal,11,17,3,0
as22.1,11,17,1,2
as24.1,9,18,0,4
as22.9,7,5,0,0
as19.1,6,21,2,0
as18.2,6,18,5,2
as10.2,5,21,5,0
as14.2,4,23,4,0
as15.1,4,21,1,5
as20.1,4,16,9,2
as16.1,0,27,4,0
```

Answer (score 4):

By using `pandas`, `layout` is to set up how many subplot you need in one line , here I am using 3

```
x.T.plot.pie(subplots=True, figsize=(7, 2),layout=(1,3))
```

[image]

Comment: Cool. What's the T?

Comment: @pitosalas transpose :-)

Comment: Shortcut :) I thought I'd seen that before! Where are those documented?

Comment: @pitosalas for T https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html for pie https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.pie.html

Comment: Is there anything in seaborn to make it prettier?

Comment: @pitosalas you can check those add in in seaborn

Comment: @pitosalas pandas' plot is base on matplot , they can accept the adjust from matplot and seaborn

Comment: I'm having a problem that all my plots are ovals. In Jupyter,

Comment: @pitosalas It work fine in my side , Ps I am using pycharm

Comment: Well my real dataset is a big bigger. let me see if I can give it to you to experiment with?

Comment: If you want your pies to be round, you have to have a figure with an aspect ratio (width/height) proportional to the  number of lines and columns in your layout. You seem to be plotting 10 lines of 4 columns each, so you should adjust your `figsize=` so that is a multiple of 4 in width and a multiple of 10 in height (e.g. `figsize=(8,20)`) or something close to that.